# C++ Macro wrap a external function and add it to a Class

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm using C++ / wasm(WebAssembly) to render with webgl inside the browser. For that to happen I import all webgl functions(a lot of functions 30+), and wrap them in a c++ class. Since there are a lot of functions my file size is getting ridiculous big (import + wrapper).

Example for one function (this is an external js function):

```
importfrom("webgl") void viewport(GLhandle deviceRef, GLsizei x, GLsizei y, GLsizei w, GLsizei h);
```

deviceRef is a (int) handle to the rendering context. Inside my C++ wrapper i use this function like:

```
class WebGlRenderContext {
private:
    GLhandle contextHandle = 0;

public:
    WebGlRenderContext(GLhandle context) : contextHandle(context) { }

    inline void setViewport(GLsizei x, GLsizei y, GLsizei w, GLsizei h) {
        JsImports::viewport(contextHandle, x, y, w, h);
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to make this all within a macro, importing, create the inline wrapper and adding contextHandle as first parameter. I know there are Variadic parameters for macros but i don't think there is a way to strip the types for the inner call.

Comment: This may be silly question, but is this wrapper worth the effort just so you can type `context.action(a, b, c);` instead of `action(context, a, b, c);`?

Comment: Probably not, but I was curious if there is a way. Also, I prefer having the functions bound to the state then have to keep them around with a separate state.